# Filter JSON for keys & values using other JSON objects

Tags: java, json, mongodb, gson

I'm currently having the following issue:

I wish to loop through a set of JSON files. I want to filter out certain JSON files that match a filter. This filter is another JSON object.

MongoDB is able to do this; you give a JSON object as parameter and it will list documents containing the given JSON elements.

I need a flatfile version of this, but I am not able to succeed. I'm using GSON as my JSON library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consumes an array of file paths that each contain a JSON string, and a `JsonObject` that represents the filter rules. Returns a list of file paths that match the filter rules.

```
public List<String> filter(String[] filePaths, JsonObject rules) throws FileNotFoundException {
        final List<String> filtered = new ArrayList<String>();
        final Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> rulesEntries = rules.entrySet();
        for (String path : filePaths) {
            final Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(path))));
            final JsonObject file = jsonParser.parse(reader).getAsJsonObject();
            final Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> fileEntries = file.entrySet();
            if (fileEntries.containsAll(rulesEntries)) filtered.add(path);
        }
        return filtered;
    }
```

Comment: The return statement for my method **must** be `Map<String, Entry<JsonObject, Long>>`, with String being the filename. Got an answer on that? I'm an absolute beginner to using JSON like this, so that would be helpfull ;)

Comment: @DennisvanderVeeke Every `JsonObject` has multiple `Entry<String, JsonElement>` where the `String` is a key and the `JsonElement` a value. What does `Entry<JsonObject, Long>` represent? If that `JsonObject` is the  json object associated with a path, what does the `Long` represent?

Comment: it represents the last modified time. This can easily be accessed with `file.lastModified()`

Comment: In order to have an `Entry<JsonObject, Long>` you need to have a `Map<JsonObject, Long>` because an entry is a key-value pair of a map. You cannot just create an entry, set it's key, value and add it as a value to a different map, in this case `Map<String, Entry<JsonObject, Long>>`.

Comment: Alright, I have fixed it, although there's a bug in your code that I noticed. You create an entry set of the rules twice by accident, and in the if statement, you compare those two entry sets, which are obviously the same, so it always returns true. Create your second (above the if statement) entry set from the file variable, not the rules, then it works. Thanks alot!

Comment: @niklabaz Adding a 3rd party library and accumulating a value to be parsed to a String may be too expensive: passing a `final Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(path))))` is cheaper along with `jsonParser.parse(reader).getAsJsonObject()` due to some performance costs in `Gson`.